# PHP Curl - eBay CSV FileExchange

Tags: php

I've tried to send a CSV File to eBay FileExchange Service.

I'm writing an application to update a lot of products on eBay at the same time.
When I upload the test.csv by using the eBay CSV-Manager the update will be success, but with the script nothing will happens after post the data.

I've treid the following steps:

Create a separate token for FileExchange.
https://signin.ebay.de/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&runame=F-FILEEXL51P1EHH6L899Q9B969GE134DK-FileUpload

Then I use the following script:

```
$token     = 'AgAAAA**AQAAAA**aAAAAA************';

$ebay_url = 'https://bulksell.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?FileExchangeUpload';

$sendheaders = array(
'User-Agent: My Client App v1.0'
);

$fields = array(
'token' => $token,
'file' => '@test.csv'
);

$ch = curl_init($ebay_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0); // set to 1 to eliminate body info from response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0); // use HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response. ###
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $sendheaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields); // use HTTP POST to send form data

$resp = curl_exec($ch); //execute post and get results

if(!curl_exec($ch)) {
die('Error: ' . curl_error($ch) . ' - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}   

curl_close ($ch);
```

I've used this csv File-format (test.csv)

Action;ItemID;DispatchTimeMax
Revise;28*********916;30

The results after post:

```
print_r($resp);
```

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: dp1=bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**617d3da3^bl/DE617d3da3^; Domain=.ebay.com; Expires=Sat, 30-Oct-2021 12:42:11 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: s=CgAD4ACBdvCgjMjFkNjZkMDcxNmUwYTBmMTc1MTA0ZmEwZmZmYjEyZWFY39RE; Domain=.ebay.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: nonsession=CgADKACBhfT2jMjFkNjZkMDcxNmUwYTBmMTc1MTA0ZmEwZmZmYjEyZWIAywABXbrdqzHTwXKU; Domain=.ebay.com; Expires=Sat, 30-Oct-2021 12:42:11 GMT; Path=/
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 731
Date: Thu, 31 Oct 2019 12:42:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

File upload successful. Your ref # is .
Close

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

Obviously at php 7.1 the @ has no effect, and the file post ist empty to ebay.

I use the curl_file_create function and it's work.

```
if (!function_exists('curl_file_create'))
{
    function curl_file_create($filename, $mimetype = '')
    {
        return "@$filename;filename="           
            . ($mimetype ? ";type=$mimetype" : '');
    }
}

$fields = array(
    "token" => $token,
    "file" =>  curl_file_create ($_GET['filename'], 'text/csv')
);
```

Hope that help's anybody.